# GWT - how to get the tabText of selected tab?

Tags: java, gwt, tabpanel

I want to get the tab text when I click on a tab. I do this:

```
tabPanel.addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<Integer>() {

            @Override
            public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<Integer> event) {
                //get the tabtext here
            }
        });
```

But I only get the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using `TabPanel` and you haven't provided a custom `Widget` for the `TabBar`, you could do this:

```
tabPanel.addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<Integer>() {

  @Override
  public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<Integer> event) {
      String tabHtml = tabPanel.getTabBar().getTabHTML(event.getSelectedItem());
    }
  });
```

Of course, you will get the underlying HTML of the tab, that generally is a `<div>tab text</div>`. The text you put in the `add()` methods are wrapped in either a `Label`, or an `HTML` widget, whether you have chosen to display the tab text as HTML.

Of course this is not handy, generally you need to store somewhere the tab text (in a `TabPanel` extension I'd guess, or a model) at insertion time (overriding the `add(...)`s) and retrieve it when needed (by adding a simple getter for them).

Comment: @ Andrea Boscolo, I am using com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TabPanel
, but I am not able to find tabPanel.getTabHTML().

Comment: @Ranna Sorry, typo. you have to pass from the `TabBar`. Fixed.

Comment: @Ranna I'm not a 'she' btw :D

Comment: I know @AndreaBoscolo :), but I think kArvee hasn't noticed. well this method will return you the whole html content within it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected tab by following.

```
tabPanel.getElement().getTitle();
```

Comment: getTitle is only the tooltip not the tab text If Im right. But thank you anyways.